# How to upgrade for all extensions installed in the database for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I need to update all the extensions in a database, not just one.

Is thete a goodwway to do that?

Perhaps this command is useful for this, it shows the installed extensions:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Yes, this is a question, I would like to know the answer to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `psql`, it could be as simple as

```
SELECT format(
          'ALTER EXTENSION %I UPDATE;',
          extname
       )
FROM pg_extension \gexec
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using dynamic SQL:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_sql text;
  l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in select extname from pg_extension loop
    l_sql := format('alter extension %I update', l_rec.extname);
    execute l_sql;
  end loop;
end;
$$
```